# Cookies in browser console is different than cookies fetch from Laravel

Tags: laravel

I get two different values from the console and from the Laravel side.

This is how I get from the Laravel side

```
public function getCookies() {

    $cookies = \Cookie::get();

    dd($cookies);


}
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

It seems the cookies will be automatically decrypted when get function is called. 
Is there any way I could get the original value of the cookies without getting decrypted?

**EDIT 2**

Resolved this by including the cookies name in except array in EncryptCookies middleware. If you are interested in more of this discussion, can refer

1. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6679
2. https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel will automatically encrypt and decrypt all cookies.

> All cookies created by the Laravel framework are encrypted and signed with an authentication code, meaning they will be considered invalid if they have been changed by the client.
>   Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#cookies

You can exclude a cookie from the automatic encryption by adding it to the [$except array in the EncryptCookies middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4882961b418455e942c2dab85cdb55272c80776b/app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php#L14-L16).

Comment: I already did include the cookies name in the except array. But unfortunately, it still gives me null.

Comment: FYI, the cookies is set by the Javascript, not Laravel. I just need to read on the Laravel side

Comment: Opps. I did something stupid. I added the except in the Illuminate folders instead of my local middleware. Which have empty except array